# Remove hard link when target is locked by system process

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, ln, locked-files, csrss.exe

I've created a hard link (not symbolic link) `Arial.ttf` in my user directory using the Git for Windows GNU tool `ln.exe` and Bash. The link points to the system font `C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf`.

```
ln /c/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf ~/Fonts/Arial.ttf
```

The Windows font file and (for some reason) my link, are constantly locked for use by `csrss.exe`, which is a process described by [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_scanning/csrssexe/26bba20c-2691-4d42-bec4-637436c53c4f) as:

> ...the user-mode portion of the Win32 subsystem (with Win32.sys being the kernel-mode portion). Csrss stands forclient/server run-time subsystem and is an essential subsystem that must be running at all times.

Hence, I assume it is impossible to kill the process without risking serious stability issues, and the link file cannot be deleted while locked.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Use a windows native tool like `mklink` instead to create it or add the fonts folder do your path? Why are you even creating that link? Or create an actual copy of the file?

Comment: I certainly will do one of those things, once I can clean up the mess I've created for myself.

Comment: That's not a symbolic link though...

Comment: @grawity I see what you're getting at. After reading a little on [the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29786294/3803805), I've edited my question to refer to a hard link, not symbolic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution was to reboot into safe mode with command prompt, and remove the files using the command line.

I also wrote a wrapper function for `ln` so that I can use `mklink` to make Windows symlinks with the command `ln -s`.